# Get a list of users who have liked a media -> not working anymore

Tags: instagram

I realized, that since Sunday, 8th December 2013 the Instagram API do not return the correct count of users who has liked a media.

Example: For a media with 500 likes the API returns a list with only about 120 users.

Before Sunday everything works well and I do not have any notification from Instagram changing there policy on this topic.

The official Instagram API Console returns the same amount of users like my app, and therefore I think the Instagram API has a bug or they changed the policy.

Do everybody noticed the same issue?

Thanks a lot for any feedback helping to solve the problem!
Joseph

Answer (score 9):

Instagram appears to have changed their /likes API end point recently.  The changes/errors I've noticed are:

- The count parameter is ignored.
- Up to a maximum of 120 likes are returned, but the number may be less due to likes from deleted accounts (these are included in the count to 120, but not included in the returned data)
- The pagination feature of the likes endpoint is no longer being returned (ie only 1 page of likes data is being returned).
- With an authorised access_token (ie from the user's login), you are unable to retrieve the likes information from media on a private account.

Previously, up to 1000 likes were available per photo via the pagination process.

Like you, I have seen no official announcement of the changes in their API.  I continue to be disappointed by their serial lack of communication and constant removal of features from the API.

Comment: I'm fully agree with you, the unreliability and all the new restrictions are very disappointing. I have some understanding for Instagram, they are growing fast, but using the API we need some consistency and a bit of clear communication... Let's wait and see the next changes.

Answer (score 4):

Instagram has always limited the number of likes returned in the `{media_id}/likes` endpoint to ~100. This is to reduce load on their servers (and to protect the API client from not crashing trying to load potentially thousands of likers in the resultant payload). They do not paginate the list of likers either, unfortunately.

Note though, that in the case where likes exceeds 120, that the number of likers returned in the `/likes` endpoint is entirely different than the `count` property returned on the `{media_id}` endpoint itself.

For example:

[`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/607348114809499642_58658/likes`](https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/607348114809499642_58658/likes)

returns only 120 likes in the array, whereas

[`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/607348114809499642_58658`](https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/607348114809499642_58658)

indicates the count is `6930`

**Update**

It appears these results may now be paginated as they appear in the official app paginated. However, as TomRoggero points out below, that may not actually be available in the API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but this is not the whole truth. Yes, there is a limitation, but before Sunday the request https://api.instagram.com/v1/media//607348114809499642_58658/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN returned 1000 data sets. This is really true! So, I think Instagram has changed this limitation from 1000 to something around 120 data sets (users who liked a media). Unfortunately there is no information about this limitation, and this is very sad.

Comment: I've never seen likes return more than 100 or so results: not in the Instagram app, any of the apps I've developed on the IG platform, or in any of the popular 3rd party apps? Here's one of [mine on Statigram](http://statigr.am/p/541686453680574252_909450) for example, and while it's got 1306 likes, only 120 appear in the list.

Comment: I am getting 120 as well, which is weird. I'm not sure what is was before but it definitely wasn't exactly 120... there is also a bug with likes on private photos maybe this has something to do with it (a photo of mine for reference http://statigr.am/p/480646617176107470_319505) only shows 118 likes

Comment: 18 months ago it was 100 -- in the app, in all the 3rd party apps, and the API. There have always been changes, but if for some reason it was spitting out 1000, that would actually be a fairly significant bug (and really bad for performance). Downside is that they don't paginate the results, which makes the list effectively useless.

Comment: @r3mus i could definitely get at least 1000 before... i used to cmd+f in my likes to see if certain people liked my photo

Comment: Well, strange that it did that - must have been a relatively recent change. But they're constantly reducing the amount of data going out to handle server load, so if it's 120 that you're getting now, it's going to stay that way until they change it again.

Comment: I am seeing the same change in maximum likes returned.  With the adjustment for deleted accounts, Instagram used to return up to 1000 likes per photo, albeit spread over multiple API requests using their pagination feature.  Since earlier this month (possibly prior to 8th December) this has reduced to 120 in a single return with no option for pagination to continue.  As techcharger says, Instagram's lack of any notification of API changes is very sad indeed.

Comment: @remus you mentioned just recently that the results may now be paginated?  Can you elaborate on how?

Comment: Sorry @alex I don't know how - just that the official app paginates the results so it's probable that the API does too.

Comment: @remus where did you take that it's now paginated? they're not

Comment: @TomRoggero I didn't, and my answer wasn't canonical. I only speculated that the API might because the official app does.

Comment: @remus i've inspected the requests the app does using a proxy. The likes aren't paginated. They're only showing 120. I've tried using a natgeo pic