# Instagram API media likes endpoint leaving off likes

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to pull likes from a photo on Instagram via their API, but it appears the API arbitrarily leaves some likes out. [I know that it caps the maximum number of media likes at 120](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478485/get-a-list-of-users-who-have-liked-a-media-not-working-anymore), but I'm testing on a piece of media that has 3 likes, but only 1 is returning. Are there limitations on what likes are returned via that endpoint that aren't documented on their [developer site](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/)?

**EDIT:** I'm seeing the in a production app that's passed the review process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in Sandbox mode then only sandbox approved users will be returned in API. Once your app is reviewed and set to live, all users will show up in API response.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available
>   in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible
>   in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:
>
> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
> - Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users
> - Reduced API rate limits

Comment: This is on a production app, I'll edit the question.

Comment: what is the `media_id`

Comment: 1171957652784949027_1690430776

Comment: Turns out that if you want to read all the likes from a user's post, you need the likes scope, even though the documentation says it only covers making or removing likes on a user's behalf. Given that information, this answer is correct.